# Python Flask Block template inheretance won't work

Tags: python, html, flask, template-inheritance

I created a simple Html file and Child html file to test a template inhertance using block

base.html

`<h1>TEST BLOCK</h1> {% block content %}{% endblock %}`

test.html

`{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}Output{% endblock %}`

I've already reasearch and tried searching so far it didn't solve my issue. The word "Output" won't show

Comment: What is your Python code?

Comment: I use a render_template in my routing. So far I can see the H1 tag text but the block won't show

Comment: I'm rusty with flask, but personally I'd copy the [example here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/), confirm it works, then trim it down until you have the equivalent of what you've got now.

Comment: Hi peter, I've copied the sample but it still dosen't work.  The Child template won't show the other words. All its showing is the copy right thing.

Comment: I've already solved it. Thank you peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a solved already the issue. Please see below for the solution

base.html

```
 <h1>Hello</h1>{% block content %} {% endblock %}
```

child.html

```
{% include 'base.html' %}
{% block content %} World {% endblock %}
```

The issue was in my routing it was routing to the base template when it should've routing to the child template. Since in the child template it will also show the "Hello".

issue:

```
@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('base.html')
```

solved:

```
@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('child.html')
```

Comment: This is why I mentioned you should show your python code too, if you leave something out your question then it could end up important (like it was in this case)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I'll keep note on this for future cases. Thank you again peter